# stmaryrd and boldsymbol: avoid warnings

Tags: symbols, amsmath, bold, warnings, stmaryrd

Here are two examples:

1

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    $\boldsymbol x$
\end{document}
```

2

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
    $\boldsymbol x$
\end{document}
```

As far as I can see, both versions produce the same output when compiled with `pdflatex`: there is a single "x" in bold italics.

However, when I compile document 2, I also get the following warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/stmry/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `U/stmry/m/n' instead on input line ….
```

Why do I get this warning (which seems to suggest that Latex was *not* able to find the right font) but correct output?

How do I avoid the warning? I need both of the following in my document:

- *bold* versions of normal math symbols (something that I can easily produce without `stmaryrd`)
- *regular* versions of some symbols that are only provided in `stmaryrd`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Internally `\boldsymbol` effectively uses `\boldmath` so sets up an entire bold math setup whatever symbols are actually used in bold, hence you get this warning.

The [`silence`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/silence) package gives an interface for filtering out various LaTeX messages so you could filter out these or in this case, [`stmaryrd`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/stmaryrd/) uses

```
\SetSymbolFont{stmry}{bold}{U}{stmry}{b}{n}
                                     %%%
```

To declare that the bold math version should use the bold font (which is never declared as it doesn't exist).

So an alternative would be to tell LaTeX to use the normal font in the bold version.

I get no warnings for this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\SetSymbolFont{stmry}{bold}{U}{stmry}{m}{n}
                                     %%%
\begin{document}


aa
    $\boldsymbol{x}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @JukkaSuomela try now:-)

Comment: This works, but (as expected) also hides valid warnings: `$\boldsymbol{\llbracket}$`, for example, produces no warnings and simply silently fails producing a bold `⟦` (⟦ is one of the symbols `stmaryrd` defines). Is there a way of hiding the warning only when it is indeed spurious, thus, only when the document does not actively try to use bold symbols from the St Mary’s Road font? And, relatedly, can this problem be somehow corrected by changing the code of the `stmaryrd` package? (In which case I’d try to contact the authors.)

Comment: @OlivierCailloux not easily as (unlike math alphabets \mathsf etc) math symbol fonts have to be set up before the math is started so symbols can be assigned fixed `\mathchardef` values so the font warning comes at that point even if you have no math at all.

Comment: Note that the snippet code has to be inserted before packages using bold maths. For example,
`\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\SetSymbolFont{stmry}{bold}{U}{stmry}{m}{n}`
will produce a warning but 
`\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\SetSymbolFont{stmry}{bold}{U}{stmry}{m}{n}
\usepackage{bm}`
will not.

Comment: @Flewer47 as documented, `bm` if it is used must be loaded after any other changes to the math font setup so your first snippet is user error.

Comment: I know it does not make any sense to post a comment here after all this time, but maybe this might help. About the silence package, the line to insert are : `\usepackage{silence}
\WarningsOff[latexfont]`