# Is there a good replacement for stmaryrd?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, latin-modern, stmaryrd

I am getting various warnings because of St. Mary Rd. fonts (stmaryrd) which I get around using tricks like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106714/stmaryrd-and-boldsymbol-avoid-warnings) and anyfontsize.

Is there a good replacement for St. Mary Rd. (like Latin Modern fonts in place of Computer Modern fonts) that I can use with pdfLaTeX?

Comment: Can you show these warnings with a MWE?

Comment: @egreg, If you want an example see the linked post. In any case, I am not asking here how to get rid of those warnings, I know how to do that. I want to know if there is a good more modern replacement for `stmaryrd`.

Comment: There's no bold `stmaryrd`. For "replacement", one should know what symbols precisely you need.

Comment: @egreg, I know, I got around that and other warnings. As I wrote I am not trying to resolve any warning right now, I don't have an unsolved warning issue. I just want to know about good more modern replacements for the package.

Comment: There is no *more modern replacement for `stmaryrd`*.

Comment: @egreg, actually I looked around a bit more after posting the question and it seems to me that the symbols in stmaryrd can can obtained in Latin Modern Math (thought not with the same commands). So in this sense there is a replacement. The problem is that it requires XeTeX/LauTeX. I am hoping there is something similar that I can use in LaTeX. In short, by replacement I don't mean a backward-compatible upgrade of stmaryrd that I can simply but something that provides the those symbols (possibly using other names for those symbols).

Comment: I saw your other question. Again, what are the symbols you need? Are there compelling reasons to use bold versions of them, or is this just curiosity? If it's curiosity, the answer is no, there's no "more modern replacement", whatever you mean by "more modern".

Comment: @egreg, I used the cheat suggested in the other question, and right now I am not looking for any particular symbol. The question is not just out of curiosity. In general stmarysd causes too many issues for me and each time I spend considerable time trying to solve them. I am looking for a more permanent solution to these troubles by using a more robust package in place stmaryrd which provides similar symbols. In short, I am looking for a long term solution to my problems with this package, not a fix to some particular issue.