# Beamer, stmaryrd and boldsymbol

Tags: beamer, errors, warnings, boldsymbol, stmaryrd

When compiling this code:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\SetSymbolFont{stmry}{bold}{U}{stmry}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
 $\boldsymbol{x}$
\end{document}
```

I get these warnings:

```
Font shape `U/stmry/b/n' undefined(Font) using `U/stmry/m/n' instead
Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

Why? How can I solve the problem or remove the warnings? (I also get them with pdfLaTeX.)

Comment: There is no bold version of the `stmaryrd` fonts, as far as I know. Remove the `\SetSymbolFont` declaration.

Comment: Ok, but erasing that line does not remove the warning. I put it there after reading this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106714/stmaryrd-and-boldsymbol-avoid-warnings?rq=1

Comment: The suggestion is to do `\SetSymbolFont{stmry}{bold}{U}{stmry}{m}{n}`

Comment: Honestly I didn't notice, and the guy who answered has even put some "%" characters in his code to mark the difference (which is another thing I've only realized now). I'm very sorry for the silly question.